# How do I send a RSA signed message to tomcat error

Tags: spring-ws

I created a webservice using spring ws. When I try to access the service I get the following error

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [messageDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.utils.XMLUtils.decode(Ljava/lang/String;)[B] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.utils.XMLUtils.decode(Ljava/lang/String;)[B
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.token.BinarySecurity.getToken(BinarySecurity.java:205) ~[wss4j-ws-security-common-2.2.4.jar!/:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.token.X509Security.getX509Certificate(X509Security.java:90) ~[wss4j-ws-security-common-2.2.4.jar!/:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.BinarySecurityTokenProcessor.getCertificatesTokenReference(BinarySecurityTokenProcessor.java:139) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.BinarySecurityTokenProcessor.handleToken(BinarySecurityTokenProcessor.java:77) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.engine.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:340) ~[wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.validateMessage(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:678) ~[spring-ws-security-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.handleRequest(AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-ws-security-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:227) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:176) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:89) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar!/:8.5.34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_222]
```

This is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.cs</groupId>
    <artifactId>countryService</artifactId>
<!--    <packaging>war</packaging>-->
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>countryService Spring-WS Application</name>
    <url>http://www.springframework.org/spring-ws</url>


<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
<version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<!--<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>-->



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.security/wss4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.19</version>
</dependency>
<!--
test dependency
-->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wss4j/wss4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j-ws-security-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-security/xmlsec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-security</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j-ws-security-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


   <build>
        <finalName>CountryService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


<plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.mycompany.cs.Application</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>            

<plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </plugin>
<!--<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</schemaDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
-->
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</schemaDirectory>
          <schemaIncludes>
            <include>*.wsdl</include>
          </schemaIncludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Does someone have an idea what's going wrong? One additional hint: When using the spring client it works. Now I try to use gSOAP to sign the messages, and then there is the Exception. Signing seems to be not the problem, because there is no error message using the provided methods

Comment: Well the error message is "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.utils.XMLUtils.decode(Ljava/lang/String;)B". This appears to come from [Apache Santuario xmlsec](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.santuario/xmlsec). Can you look at `mvn dependency:tree` to make sure you're including it and there aren't e.g. version conflicts where one dependency expects a specific version of the class and another dependency includes the wrong version of the class?

Comment: In particular you're including [xml-security xmlsec](ttps://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-security/xmlsec) explicitly. This may not be one the other dependencies expect.

Comment: I checked the dependencies and removed the xmlsec, but the problem still occours

Comment: I added the dependency
     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4</version>
</dependency>

now there is an NullPointerException

Comment: You shouldn't have to add it: 2.1.0 is already included as a dependency of spring-ws-security 3.0.4. Can you investigate the NullPointerException and see where it's coming from? Is it likely to be an initialization error, or an error with your data, or a bug in the Apache code, or something else?

Comment: The NullPointerException now seems to be an Certificate issue. Tomcat logs that it can't validate the my signature. I have to investifǵate that. Is ist possible, that cetificates loose some information while converting between jks, pem, pc12 etc.??